# What does the flashing lightning icon over minions mean?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was playing Dominion and noticed that when my minions started attacking a point (and slowly capturing it) that a little icon started flashing above them. I took a screenshot of it.

[image: League of Legends minions with lightning bolts above their head]

I'm guessing it's to alert me that they are making progress, but I'm not totally sure what the symbol means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recently all of the status effects in League of Legends were standardized, specifically, Stuns, Fears, Blinds, Silences, and **Taunts**. What you are seeing is the *Taunted* debuff.

The way points work in Dominion, is that they taunt nearby enemy minions to attack them (and in the process, capture the point).